# Chrome Extension: Loading the WebPage without changing the Source Code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have designed a Chrome Extension, where I have an input box and a submit Button. Whenever I am inputing a locale, it changes the lang attribute value (`<html lang="ab-CD">`) of the page. I can see that fonts get changed when I submit. But I want to see the change similar to when I actually changes the lang attribute in source code and refresh the page. In this case I see all the resource bundles loaded as per the lang of html page while through chrome extension, I can only see some fonts changed, that's all.

Please suggest a way out where I can see html page loaded completed as per the lang I input from chrome extension.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Just changing the language in the file will most probably not affect the content: the server has already decided what to serve and sends you the response. Unless you have a very specific case of dynamic content being loaded after static HTML was served, I don't see what you're achieving.

Comment: This may be an XY problem: you can, if you want, modify the navigator settings that are sent to the server as language preferences. That may affect things, but again, it depends on how the site in question works.

Comment: Hi Xan, Thanks for prompt reply.
If I change the lang attribute using chrome extension. How I can reload the page with changed lang attribute. If I will reload it with F5 it will reload as per the static source code.

Is there anyway, I can reload the page with the changed lang attribute, that will also serve my purpose.
Thanks!

Comment: I explained why it won't work, but you can do it with a content script defined in the manifest.

Comment: You can hook into network requests and modify parameters or headers after a location reload call.

Comment: Hi @ZigMandel, Can you please direct me to some link for the way you suggested.

Comment: I havent used it this way but I think it may be possible with this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

Comment: Hi Zig, I spent sometime reading about the webRequestAPI but still clueless. My requrirement is simple can I pass document.documentElement.lang="ab-CD" through webRequest so that my webpage will load with <html lang="ab-CD">  instead of <html lang="en">

Any help will be fine !!